# Polynomial Operator Overloading

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I have some problem on my code.

I need to enter a polynomial as a list of coefficient-exponent pairs using `operator>>`, then I need to print it in the following way:

```
coefficient*x**exponent+coefficient*x**exponent...
```

I think my code is correct, but nothing gets printed.

### HEADERS

```
#ifndef POLYNOMIAL_H
#define POLYNOMIAL_H

#include <cctype>
#include <iomanip>
#include "Element.h"

class Polynomial
{
    public:
        Polynomial ( int size = 0) // initializes size of the polynomial
        {
            this->size = size;
            ptr_array = new Element[size] ;
        }

        static void InitializePolynomial ( Polynomial * );
        friend istream &operator>>( istream &, Polynomial & );
        friend ostream &operator<<( ostream &, const Polynomial & );

        int Getsize ( );
        Element GetElement (int);

    private:
        int size; // numbers of the terms in a polynomial
        Element *ptr_array; // A pointer array that stores pointers to the objects of Element
};

#endif 

#ifndef ELEMENT_H
#define ELEMENT_H

#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

class Element
{
    public:
        Element( int exponent = 0, double coefficient = 0 )
        {
            this->exponent = exponent;
            this->coefficient = coefficient;
        }

    void SetCoefficient ( double );
    void SetExponent ( int );
    double GetCoefficient ( );
    int GetExponent ( );

    private:
        int exponent;
        double coefficient;
};

#endif
```

### CPP

```
#include "Polynomial.h"

void Polynomial :: InitializePolynomial ( Polynomial * Poly )
{
    int size;
    cout << "Initialisation of the polynomial" << endl;
    cout << "What is the size of your polynomial ? ";
    cin >> size;
    Poly = new Polynomial (size);
}

Element Polynomial :: GetElement(int i)
{
    return ptr_array[i];
}

istream &operator>>( istream &input, Polynomial &Poly )
{
    int i;

    for (i=0; i<12; i++)
    {
        double tempcoef;
        int tempexp;

        input>>tempcoef; 
        Poly.ptr_array[i].SetCoefficient(tempcoef);
        input.ignore(1,',');

        input>>tempexp; 
        Poly.ptr_array[i].SetExponent(tempexp);
        input.ignore(1,',');
    }

    return input;
}

/*
ostream &operator<<( ostream &output , Polynomial const &Poly )
{
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<12;i++)
    {
        if (i != 0) output<<setfill('+')<<setw(1);
        output<<Poly.ptr_array[i].GetCoefficient();
        output<<setfill('*')<<setw(1);
        output<<Poly.ptr_array[i].GetExponent();
        output<<setfill('*')<<setw(2);
    }

    return output;
}*/

ostream &operator<<(ostream &output, const Polynomial &polynom)
{

    for(int i=0; i< polynom.size ; i++)
    {
        if(pow(polynom.ptr_array[i].GetCoefficient(), polynom.ptr_array[i].GetExponent()) != 0)
        {
            if(i > 0 && (polynom.ptr_array[i].GetCoefficient() >= 0))
            {
                output<<"+";
            }

            if(polynom.ptr_array[i].GetExponent() == 0)
            {
                output<<polynom.ptr_array[i].GetCoefficient();
            }

            else if(polynom.ptr_array[i].GetExponent() == 1)
            {
                output<<polynom.ptr_array[i].GetCoefficient()<<"x";
            }

            else
            {
                output<<polynom.ptr_array[i].GetCoefficient()<< "*x**" << polynom.ptr_array[i].GetExponent();
            }
        }
    }
    output << endl;
    return output;
}

#include "Element.h"

void Element :: SetCoefficient ( double Coeff )
{
    coefficient = Coeff;
}

void Element :: SetExponent ( int Expo )
{
    exponent = Expo;
}

double Element :: GetCoefficient ( )
{
    return coefficient;
}

int Element :: GetExponent ( )
{
    return exponent;
}
```

### MAIN

```
#include "Element.h"
#include "Polynomial.h"

int main ( )
{
    Polynomial FirstPolynomial;

    Polynomial :: InitializePolynomial( &FirstPolynomial );

    cout << "You are creating your polynomial" << endl;
    cout << "Please enter the coefficient et exponent like that " << endl;
    cout << "(Coefficient, Exponent, Coefficient, Exponent ...)" << endl;
    cout << "--> ";

    cin >> FirstPolynomial;
    cout << FirstPolynomial;
}
```

Comment: What happens when you step through your code line by line?

Comment: Didn't you create a question just like that yesterday and it got closed?

Comment: Before asking a question, try to pin-point where the problem is, and if you still can't solve it, then ask. Don't just throw some code here and expect people to do everything for you.

Comment: it is like if i was always in `cin >> FirstPolynomial`

Comment: man, this question was big :)

Comment: @emartel yes i had, but it is not the same exercise, we need to use two methods

Comment: @David No, there are 0 errors

Comment: @Lucas if it got closed because your "homework" was not fit for this site, what makes you think this new question is better?

Comment: @emartel i don't know why the previous one has been closed .. I'm new on this website sry

Comment: @Lucas your question is very specific as in "fix my code"

Comment: possible duplicate of [String subscript out of range](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13427570/string-subscript-out-of-range)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is most likely in `InitializePolynomial`: You pass a pointer to that function, but inside the function it is still a local variable which means changes made to the variable (like assigning to that pointer) will be reflected on the argument once the function returns. You have to pass the argument as a *reference*:

```
static void InitializePolynomial ( Polynomial *& );
```

---

Actually, reading your code again, you have a much bigger problem than that in the function: You try to allocate memory for an object that *is already allocated!*

When you declare the variable `FirstPolynomial` in the `main` function, the compiler will allocate that object for you. You should initialize it properly in `main` instead:

```
int main()
{
    int size;
    cout << "Initialisation of the polynomial" << endl;
    cout << "What is the size of your polynomial ? ";
    cin >> size;

    Polynomial FirstPolynomial(size);

    // ...
}
```

No need to have the separate initialization function.

Comment: Thank you very much, the problem was here.